# Archive-custome_post.php template not working

Tags: templates, template-hierarchy

I have a site on WordPress 3.6.1 and I created a custom post type for recipes with the code:

```
 add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_my_recipes' );
    function register_cpt_my_recipes() {
    $args = array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields' ,'tag' , 'excerpt', 'thumbnail'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
     /* Not necessary but added as a solution */
    'rewrite'=> array( 'slug' => 'my_recipes', 'with_front' => true ),
    'capability_type' => 'post'
    );
    register_post_type( 'my_recipes', $args );
    /* Not necessary but added as a solution */
    flush_rewrite_rules( false );
    }
```

I created `archive-my_recipes.php` custom template file but whenever I navigate to `mysite/my_recipes/`
I end up with code from `archive.php` with all my posts not just posts form my custom post type.
I tried `taxonomy-my_recipes.php` but also didn't work .

also `single-my_recipes.php` is working fine.

I read about the subject on the WordPress documentation site  [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates)

This is the `body_class` output:

```
[ archive post-type-archive post-type-archive-Array logged-in admin-bar custom-font-enabled single-author customize-support ]
```

I added :

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'recipes' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

to function.php to include my custom post types in the main query.

Comment: Can we see a live example? Failing that, can you provide the actual URL, the non-rewritten URL, and the output of the `body_class()` function?

Comment: this is the body class output [ archive post-type-archive post-type-archive-Array logged-in admin-bar custom-font-enabled single-author customize-support ]

Comment: Please **edit your question** to add clarifying information, so that it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Comment: `post-type-archive-Array` is a problem. That should say `post-type-archive-my_recipes`. What else are you doing to modify the query for archive indexes?

Comment: where is that ?

Comment: "*where is that ?*" - Where is what?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand your comment . post-type-archive-Array where it is that should be renamed as you suggested.

Comment: `post-type-archive-Array` isn't something that you *rename*. It's a *symptom*, not a *cause*. I'm pretty sure it means that, when WordPress asks, "*what post-type is this query?*", the response it gets is `Array()` - as in, multiple post-types. So, you'll need to find where that's happening, because it's not default behavior.

Comment: I added this part form the documentation :Custom Post Types in the Main Query

Comment: "*I added this part form the documentation :Custom Post Types in the Main Query*" - I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Please **edit your question** to explain this detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pre_get_posts` filter is incorrect. You are altering more queries than I think you think you are. The "main" query isn't just the primary index. You are adding (or attempting to add) all of those post types to every page, basically,-- the author archives, the categories, everything.

Try this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( 
      !is_admin() 
      && $query->is_main_query() 
      && 'my_recipes' != $query->get('post_type')
    ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'my_recipes' ) );
    }
}
```

Your `archive-my_recipes.php` should work now. I don't know if that the correct solution though. My suspicion is that you want `is_home` or `is_front_page` so that you only adding the additional post types to a particular index. Something like:

```
function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( 
      $query->is_home() 
      && $query->is_main_query()
    ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'my_recipes' ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that already and I used if ( !is_admin() && is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) it work fine now as I just need to add it to categories only